# After a successful docker build, why do i still get the error; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, docker

I have a fastapi app running in a docker container. I would think that all dependencies are installed during the build run. After a successful build, i SSH into the backend docker service to access the database in order to migrate and seed the development database with the following commands:

```
docker-compose exec backend sh
# Install poetry
apt-get -qq update 
apt-get -qq -y install curl
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
export PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

# Install Poetry task runner poe, might take long to install
poetry add --group dev poethepoet

# Migrate the changes
poetry run poe migratedb

# For seeding the database with sample data use 
poetry run poe seed_db

# Exit the backend service shell
exit
```

Now when i run the last command; `poetry run poe seed_db` i get the error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/app/commands/seed_db.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import insert, select
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

I have ran `poetry add sqlalchemy`, output paraphrased says;

> The package is already present in the pyproject.toml and will be skipped.

Here's my Dockerfile;

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.9-slim AS compile_step

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc

# Make a folder where our built packages would be
RUN mkdir -p /build/wheels

# Convert our dependencies from poetry to pip format
COPY pyproject.toml ./poetry.lock* /app/
RUN pip3 install -U pip wheel poetry
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt --without-hashes -o /tmp/requirements.txt

# Compile all our dependencies into one wheel
RUN pip3 wheel --wheel-dir=/build/wheels -r /tmp/requirements.txt

FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn:python3.9-slim AS run_step

# Import compiled python dependencies from previous step
COPY --from=compile_step /build/wheels /tmp/wheels

# Install python dependencies
RUN pip3 install -U pip wheel
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir /tmp/wheels/* && rm -rf /tmp/wheels

ENV MAX_WORKERS=1

# Set log level of Gunicorn to debug for aiodebug package
ENV LOG_LEVEL="debug"

# Set the beginning point for uvicorn
ENV MODULE_NAME=app.application.core

COPY . /app
```

Here are the environments;

```
# poetry env info

Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.16
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/simple-ink_backend-9TtSrW0h-py3.9
Executable:     /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/simple-ink_backend-9TtSrW0h-py3.9/bin/python
Valid:          True

System
Platform:   linux
OS:         posix
Python:     3.9.16
Path:       /usr/local
Executable: /usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

Here's the pyproject file;

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "xyz backend"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
SQLAlchemy = "^1.4.22"
alembic = "^1.6.5"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.1"
asyncpg = "^0.24.0"
aiologger = "^0.6.1"
Secweb = "^1.3.0"
fastapi-jwt-auth = "^0.5.0"
# Required by fastapi
# ---------------------
fastapi = "^0.70"
email-validator = "^1.1.3"
requests = "^2.26.0"
aiofiles = "^0.7.0"
Jinja2 = "^3.0.1"
itsdangerous = "^2.0.1"
uvicorn = "^0.15.0"
orjson = "^3.6.3"
# ---------------------
# Required by alembic
# ---------------------
importlib-resources = "^5.2.2"
# ---------------------
aiodebug = "^1.1.2"
sentry-sdk = "^1.4.3"
aiocache = {extras = ["redis"], version = "^0.11.1"}
aioredis = "<2.0.0"
fastapi-key-auth = "^0.7.0"
fastapi-utils = "^0.2.1"
msgpack = "^1.0.3"
typer = "^0.4.0"
aioresponses = "^0.7.3"
when-changed = "^0.3.0"
bcrypt = "^3.2.0"
tqdm = "^4.64.0"
poethepoet = "^0.18.1"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^6.2.5"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.16"
pylint = "^2.10.2"
pytest-cov = "^3.0"
pytest-async-sqlalchemy = "^0.2"
Faker = "^9.2"
black = "^21.11b1"
isort = "^5.10.1"
when-changed = "^0.3.0"
ipykernel = "^6.6.0"
pre-commit = "^2.17.0"
pytest-mock = "^3.7.0"
poethepoet = "^0.18.0"

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
poethepoet = "^0.18.1"

[tool.poe.tasks]
seed_db = { script = "app.commands.seed_db:start()", help = "Adds random data to the database for development" }
migratedb = "alembic upgrade head"
test = "pytest"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
```

Comment: You could just try to run python shell when you ssh into backend, and then try import sqlalchemy from the shell to see if it is there.

We also need more info about your docker file, maybe you built your requirements inside an environment and you're not using that environment when you ssh into ur backend?

Comment: I have added Dockerfile, pyproject.toml, and available environments.

Answer (score 0):

Poetry creates and activates a virtual environment when installed, so packages must be installed in that environment by running `poetry install`

See https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/